# What unit is expressing the effect of this capacitor in a common emitter amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, capacitance, reactance, negative-feedback

I'm working through this handout [I3.PDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjPx83H4fHsAhVwhOAKHY7sB-8QFjAMegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoefs.uncc.edu%2Fdlsharer%2Ffiles%2F2012%2F04%2FI3.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2pgyjxSmegna20f2e4IDSu) in my attempt to understand negative feedback in amplifiers.  The following formula appears, in which the author is substituting \$v_{out}\$ and \$v_{in}\$ to arrive at the gain \$A_V\$ of a simple common emitter amplifier.  (I've pasted the excerpt below.)

[image]

It looks like \$Z_{CE}\$ is the capacitive reactance of the bypass capacitor.  My question is two-fold; first, is \$Z_{CE}\$ a  common variable to use for this (I thought capacitive reactance was \$X\$) and second, why does the author then convert it to some sort of a reciprocal unit \$1/s_{C{E}}\$ in the final equation?  Wouldn't it be easier to leave the effect of the capacitor in ohms?

Note: I usually would attribute my sources, but this handout has no author listed.  If anyone knows the author I'd appreciate being able to include his/her name here.

Comment: 1/sC is not a "reciprocal unit"; it still evaluates to ohms.

Comment: X is interchangeable with Z when the capacitor is ideal. If non ideal, like taking into account leakage conductance, you need Z because it's not purely reactive.

Comment: @Reinderien thanks for the explanation that X and Z are interchangeable for ideal capacitors.  But what IS 1/sC?

Comment: Impedance of the capacitor. It's formula is in the text.

Comment: Now I'm thoroughly confused.  Which is the impedance of the capacitor, Z(CE) or 1/s(CE)?  It can't be both, right?

Comment: \$Z_{C_E}\$ depends on the value of the capacitor and the frequency of operation. The formula for \$Z_{C_E}\$ in terms of the capacitance is \$1/(s \cdot C)\$. When you buy a capacitor part, its \$Z_{C_E}\$ will not be specified; only its capacitance value \$C\$. You need a formula to convert it to \$Z_{C_E}\$.

Comment: @AJN, thanks for the formula.  What is \$s\$ in that equation?

Comment: \$s\$ represents the frequency as a complex number. It is too big to put in a comment. It seems that you lack the knowledge of some prerequisites. You will need to go to refer to prerequisite subjects. Search for "ac analysis of linear circuits". Are you familiar with Laplace transforms?

Comment: Yes, definitely missing some prerequisites, and it seems this is one of them.  Will look into more ac analysis sources and also Laplace transforms, whatever those are!